# Strange border shown when override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) is used

Tags: swift, uiview, drawrect

I have an issue with strange and unwanted grey borders that I can not hide. The grey top and right border only occurs when I override func draw(_ rect: CGRect).

[image: Strange borders on top and right side of the button]

For test reasons, I have intentionally set a blue color for the view in layoutSubviews(). But the strange borders remain.

[image: When a border is set in layoutSubviews(), the strange borders persist]

I have one button created:

```
import UIKit

class CardView: UIButton {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {         
        //activating this function enables the borders, even when I draw a Bezier path in this function the borders doesn't disappear    
    }
}
```

12 buttons shall be displayed in the CardContainerView:

```
import UIKit

class CardContainerView: UIView {

    // Create Cards
    var cardViews = [CardView](){
        didSet {
            for card in cardViews {
                addSubview(card)
                card.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
                card.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                card.layer.borderWidth = 0
            }
        }
    }

    private(set) var grid = Grid(layout: Grid.Layout.aspectRatio(3/2))

    /// The centered rect in which the buttons are going to be positioned.
    private var centeredRect: CGRect {
        get {
            return CGRect(x: bounds.size.width * 0.025,
                          y: bounds.size.height * 0.025,
                          width: bounds.size.width * 0.95,
                          height: bounds.size.height * 0.95)
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        grid.cellCount = cardViews.count
        grid.frame = centeredRect

        for i in 0...cardViews.count {
            if let frame = grid[i] {
                cardViews[i].frame = frame
                cardViews[i].layer.cornerRadius = 10
                cardViews[i].layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
                cardViews[i].layer.borderWidth = 0.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have deactivated all borders or made them invisble for the Card and the CardContainaer but it doesn't have an effect of this borders shown above. Only commenting out the override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) disables the borders. However, I need a solution to draw something and hide the borders. Do you have any ideas? If you need the grid object as well, it can be found here: https://cs193p.stanford.edu/Fall2017/Grid.swift.zip

Comment: Could you test with non zero borderWidth, just to see ? Is draw an empty func ? It is usually advised not to have an empty draw function.

Comment: I have tested it and uploaded the image, see above. Unfortunately, no change. I know that it's not advised to have an empty function, but even when I add a UIBezierpath and draw it, the strange border remains.

Comment: Could you try to set ButtonType to .custom when you create the buttons ? See here if needed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857163/set-button-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. I have increased the height of one of my Constraints for cardContainerView in my storyboard for a step of 1. Now the lines are gone. It seems to be that rounding errors or something like this were causing this problem.